# Read .txt file line by line in Python

Tags: python, string, readfile, split

My .txt file looks like this:

![enter image description here][1]

How can I read my txt file into a string object that can be printed in the same format as above?

```
I have tried: 
    with open ("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/masterClassList.txt", "r") as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()

for item in data:
    print item
```

This code prints every character on a new line. I need the txt file to be a string in order to call string methods, particularly 'string.startswith()'

As you can see, in my IDE console, the lines are printing with a black line of spaces in between each line of content. How can I eliminate these blank lines?

Here is my working solution:

```
with open ("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/masterClassList.txt", "r") as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()
    for line in data:
        line.rstrip()

print data
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest might be:

```
data = myfile.readlines()
```

This would work w/the rest of your code -- or, you could loop directly on myfile (**inside** the `with`:-) and you'd be getting one line at a time.  Note that lines include the ending `\n` so you may want to `.strip()` them before printing &c:-)

Comment: Thank you @Alex Martelli, please refer to my edit above.

Comment: @PhilipMcQuitty he has already addressed the problem, call `.strip()` on the string

Answer (score 9):

The most memory efficient way of reading lines is:

```
with open ("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/masterClassList.txt", "r") as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        print line
```

i.e. you don't need to read the entire file in to a memory, only line by line. Here is the link to python tutorial: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects