# Practice Python: Open Text File

Tags: python

Problem on "Practice Python": http://www.practicepython.org/exercise/2014/12/06/22-read-from-file.html

Hi everyone, quick question about the opening a file and examining the contents.  The file itself contains many lines, each with the name Darth, Luke, or Lea.  The program should count the number of each name.  I came up with the following, but when I run the program, nothing happens.

```
with open('PythonText.txt', 'r') as open_file:

    file_contents = open_file.readlines()
    ##Gives a list of all lines in the document##

    numberDarth = 0
    numberLea = 0
    numberLuke = 0

    numberNames = len(file_contents)-1

    while numberNames > 0:

        if file_contents[numberNames] == 'Darth':
            numberDarth = numberDarth + 1
            numberNames - 1
        elif file_contents[numberNames] == 'Lea' :
            numberLea = numberLea + 1
            numberNames - 1
        else:
            numberLuke = numberLuke + 1
            numberNames - 1

    pass

    print('Darth =' + numberDarth)
    print('Lea = ' + numberLea)
    print('Luke =' + numberLuke)
```

Can anyone help?  I can't use a visualizer as the programs cannot read my file.

Comment: Why are you reading the file from the bottom :(  ??

Comment: Also, you put `pass` before anything is printed, so what did you expect that to do?

Comment: You are not decrementing properly. `numberNames - 1` should be `numberNames = numberNames  - 1`

Answer (score 0):

> I can't use a visualizer

You can just define your own `file_contents` list...

Anyways, you might want to check elsewhere for [Reading a file line by line in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27577788/2308683). You do not need to read the whole file into a list. This is especially bad for large files.

Since you are only scanning for names, just pick out each line and don't store the rest like below.

You also have a random `pass`, which is probably exiting your code and printing nothing. So things do happen... you just haven't printed anything else. It's encouraged you print a lot while you are learning to debug things.

So, I might suggest something like this with a dictionary.

And this will also count if multiple names appear on the same line.

```
name_counts = {'Darth': 0, 'Lea': 0, 'Luke': 0}

with open('PythonText.txt') as open_file:
    # For all lines
    for line in open_file:
        # For all names
        for name in name_counts:
            # If the name is in this line, count it
            if name in line:
                name_counts[name] += 1

print(name_counts)
```